# Python GDAL cannot find app GDAL on docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip, gdal-python-bindings

I'm trying to build an application into a docker container that uses the OSGEO/GDAL libraries in Python, which are wrappers around the GDAL program. The GDAL program appears to install ok (at least Docker reports `=> CACHED [3/9] RUN apk add --no-cache gdal` without any errors from the step that I can see) however, when I get to the step where pip is supposed to bring in the GDAL Python libraries, it fails looking for files that don't exist, which some initial searching shows is likely to mean it can't find the GDAL program. Does anyone know how to resolve or work around this?

```
Collecting GDAL~=3.5.1
#11 15.03   Downloading GDAL-3.5.1.tar.gz (752 kB)
#11 15.16      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 752.4/752.4 KB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#11 15.30   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#11 15.71   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#11 15.73   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#11 15.73   
#11 15.73   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#11 15.73   │ exit code: 1
#11 15.73   ╰─> [120 lines of output]
#11 15.73       WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
#11 15.73       running egg_info
#11 15.73       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2jyd4zlx/GDAL.egg-info
#11 15.73       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2jyd4zlx/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
#11 15.73       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2jyd4zlx/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
#11 15.73       writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2jyd4zlx/GDAL.egg-info/requires.txt
#11 15.73       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2jyd4zlx/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
#11 15.73       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2jyd4zlx/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
#11 15.73       Traceback (most recent call last):
#11 15.73         File "/tmp/pip-install-tjr9j_9m/gdal_6b994752ac484434b194dfc7ccf64728/setup.py", line 105, in fetch_config
#11 15.73           p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#11 15.73         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
#11 15.73           self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
#11 15.73         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
#11 15.73           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
#11 15.73       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'
```

Here's my dockerfile (the base image is non-negotiable, I'm afraid)

```
FROM python:3.9.12-alpine3.15

RUN apk add --no-cache gdal

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/file
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ /usr/src/app/src/
COPY main.py /usr/src/app/
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

The requirements.txt is as follows.

```
requests>= 2.25.0
numpy>=1.23.1
pillow>=9.2.0
GDAL~=3.5.1
DateTime~=4.3
bitstring~=3.1.9
behave~=1.2.6
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to install GDAL to a particular spot so that python can find it when installing its GDAL libraries, or if I need to give pip some kind of hint, or if something else entirely is going on. If anyone has worked with this library before inside a docker container, thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like the issue is that I needed `RUN apk add --no-cache gdal-dev` as well to get the bindings! There are build complications, but I'll write an official answer once I solve those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thrust of the problem was lacking gdal-dev, an additional package that separately installs the python bindings. However, once pip was able to find gdal and begin installing the python libraries, those are built from C code and several additional tools plus were needed in the image, plus some environment settings to point them to the right place. Here is the dockerfile that ultimately worked:

```
FROM python:3.9.12-alpine3.15

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc
RUN apk add --no-cache gdal
RUN apk add --no-cache gdal-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base
RUN apk add --no-cache zlib

RUN export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
RUN export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/file
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ /usr/src/app/src/
COPY main.py /usr/src/app/
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Lastly, in the requirements.txt, the current 3.5.1 GDAL bindings are for Python 3.10, so I had to downgrade the GDAL until I found one that built without errors since the Python version in the base image is pinned.